# Best practice for choosing an amount for donation on a mobile form

Tags: usability, forms, mobile-web

What would be (from a UX perspective) better solution:

1. Use radiobuttons to choose an amount (eg: 2,5/5/7,5/10) and use a large submit button 
   or
2. Use 4 buttons with the amounts on it (eg donate 2,5/donate 5/donate 7,5/donate 10) as a submit button in itself and remove the large submit button

What are your thoughts?

Comment: What is the amount for? You mention donate in point 2 - is that what this form is? Have you got a current mockup of what you're thinking of going with as it's easier to visualize your issue if we can see a representation of it.

Answer (score 6):

If it is about a donation, the more "friendly" it is the better donation you will get.
I suggest to make big clickable areas (so 1 button each time) and find a funny way to make the users want to give more >> Insist on how happy you will be instead of the ammount

**Edit :**
My fault, i didn't see it's about mobile form. I updated my mockup whith a mobile version

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhsc2u.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I doubt this suggestion will work on mobile (the question is about mobile), but I agree with the basic idea.

Comment: +1 for the nice smiley concept :) and for updating after receiving comments

Answer (score 3):

I like the **Renaud**'s answer very much. However I'd do it in a bit different way.
I'd fill the whole screen with large smiley face, and on the bottom put scrollbar with amount one wants to donate, and the donate button. The scrollbar should be 'discrete' (with only four values you allow users to donate).
When someone swipes the scrollbar, the smiley should change accordingly. Even better if you create some pretty *transitions* between the faces.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZY6RU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Maybe it should start the other way round: The smilie goes "oooh" when you slide down.

Comment: Slider will make user to donate more than a regular button. +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

I really liked the ideas mentioned by Renaud, but it seemed his idea wouldn't suit mobile use. I simplified it a bit towards mobile use:

[image]
(note: i'm a utter newbie using wireframes atm :) ).

I would suggest a simple slider bar, sliding per fixed points. I suggest smaller white dots along the scrollbar.

It might be an idea to increase the circle with the $ sign to increase with the amount donated.

Comment: Just so you're aware, [UX.SE includes a copy of Balsamiq](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/02/27/uxstackexchange/) for producing simple wireframes in the browser. Just click the little icon next to the image icon in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Display four buttons in a vertical list, each with large clickable
   areas, for both desktop and mobile.
2. Use "Donate [amount]" labels for each button to prevent ambiguity.
3. List the smallest amount first as a courtesy to the user.